# Batch tab on a form

Tags: axapta, x++

I need to have a batch tab on a form? How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the RunBaseBatch framework.  See the link for a walkthrough.  Also check Classes\Tutorial_RunbaseBatch to see a good tutorial template.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc636647.aspx

Comment: yes this do help in creating a batch job but my question was to creating a batch tab on a specific form... I was going through Class\Tutorial_RunBaseForm and form\Tutorial_RunbaseForm... Am still getting a hang around it . Please let me know if this is fine

Comment: What are you struggling on? The main thing from the Tutorial_RunbaseForm is the dialog method where it does "Dialog::newFormnameRunbase(...)" to call the form.